# Not able to retrieve documents from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the documents from firestore and store it into a list,but i am getting back `[Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot']`.Also,its not returning the list of documents but the fields as the length of array is only 2 but i have 6 documents inside "Org" Collection. I have asked similar question on SO but didn't get porper answer.

This is code i implemented to get the list of docuemnts:

```
Future<List> getHistory() async {
  List history;

  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = 
      (await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Org").get()).docs;

  history = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot).toList();

  return history;
}
@override
  initState() {
    emailInputController = new TextEditingController();
    pwdInputController = new TextEditingController();
    setlist();
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp();
    
  }
   void setlist()async {
     List list = await getHistory();
    print(list)
   }
```

I want to store all documents inside "Org" collection in a list.This is pic for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be forgetting to do something in the line

```dart
history = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot).toList();
```

Calling `map` here does nothing since you're not doing any mapping. You likely intended to call

```dart
history = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot.data()).toList();
```

which retrieves the data from each snapshot and maps it to a new list.

---

If you want the document IDs instead of the fields, do `.id` instead of retrieving the data:

```dart
history = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot.id).toList();
```

Comment: Great!! It solved the instance problem but it is returning the fields inside the documents and not list of documents

Comment: Any solution to that? @Christopher Moore

Comment: @MrunalJoshi Please clarify the issue.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hope it clarifies the issue.

Comment: @MrunalJoshi Please don't edit out the original question if you have a new question, accept or create an answer here and create a new question. You only have 2 documents in the Org collection. You must not have any fields in `Organisation 2`.

Comment: I just want to list out the names of documents "Organisation 2","Organisation1" and soo on and not their fields. eg: ["Organisation 2","ORGANISATION 1","Organisation 2","COEP","Hdjsj","abcd"]

Comment: @MrunalJoshi You're also not going to get 6 documents. You only have 2 documents in the `Org` collection.

Comment: Yup.. I have added the others through Flutter itself. Trying to figure out the reason, why its showing 2 documents

Comment: @MrunalJoshi You only have 2 documents. Showing 2 documents is expected.